# file references when concatting / uglyifing vendor scripts in grunt

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs

As I'm diving in to grunt tasks etc I have some questions about concatting/uglyfing/compressing JavaScript and CSS files. JavaScript is not the big issue for me but CSS is.

Consider a file structure like this:

```
-resources
-- js
-- css
-- vendor
--- jquery
    - jquery.min.js
--- fancybox
    - fancybox.min.js
    - fancybox.min.css
    - sprite.png
--- bootstrap
    - bootstrap.min.js
    - bootstrap.min.css
```

And I want to concat/uglify/compress all the CSS and Javascript files in the vendor folder into:

```
- resources
-- js
   - project.min.js
-- css
   - project.min.css
```

How do I do keep references for used images in the CSS intact?? For example, fancybox.min.css uses a url("..") value for background.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which CSS minifier you are using, but if you use [clean-css](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css#how-to-rebase-relative-image-urls) then it has an option to rebase URLs. I've never actually tried it, but it sounds like what you want.

To use "clean-css" you would want this Grunt package: [grunt-contrib-cssin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin)